# Can I provide Ubuntu virtual image as a appendix of book?

Tags: virtualbox, license

I work for a publishing company. We are planning to publish a book about web development, and we are going to create web applications in Ubuntu environment. But we are now considering web development novices as the major audience of the book. So we'd like to provide them with Ubuntu in virtual image for Oracle VirtualBox(the virtual image will be provided on a DVD). Given that, I'd like to know if it would be illegal to do that or violate the Ubuntu license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find such these information in these links:

[Legal](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal)

[Licensing](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing)

but I don't think there would be a problem

Virtualbox licensing:

[VBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ)

yes you can distribute any opensource os built in virtual enviornment freely.

Comment: Ah, but what about the ability to redistribute a Virtual Disk Image created by Oracle Software?  You haven't addressed that in your answer at all.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat I'll also check it individually. Thank you! :)